# Do we need web-browser specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, we have 2 web browser related tags; [web](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) and [web-browsers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browsers). This seems silly enough, but then we also have [midori](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midori) and [google-chrome](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome).

Do we really need all these tags for the same thing? You can't even install chrome on the Pi! (You have to install Chromium instead.) I can't see enough questions being asked for specific browsers.

Answer (score 4):

No, we don't need these tags. But don't worry about it too much. Bad tags will be underused and decay (or be helped to decay) over time.

Only in time can we tell which tags will be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that previously all questions under [web-browsers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browsers) were tagged [web](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web). According to the [web](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) tag wiki it is for web browsers.

> Questions regarding the installation and use of **web browsers.**

Knowing this, we decided to retag the relevant questions to [web-browsers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browsers). This left an off-topic question that we felt did not need to be retagged as it should be deleted. Assuming that this question was going to be deleted, we decided to let the [web](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) tag be automatically purged after 24 hours.